# invokeMember in nested div

Tags: c#, html, css, xpath, webbrowser-control

I'm using Windows Forms Apps and webbrowser control and would like to make my code pick a certain value on a websites dropdown list. I have inspected the element on the website (see below):

```
<div class= "selectize-control">
    <div class="selectize-dropdown">
        <div class = "selectize-dropdown-content">
            <div data-value ="1" data-selectable class ="option">Option1 </div>
            <div data-value ="2" data-selectable class ="option"> Option2 </div>
            <div data-value ="2" data-selectable class ="option"> Option3 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<span style="display: none;" class= "ValidationMessage" id="ValidationMessage_1"></span>
```

I thought I could select "Option2" with writing the following code:

```
 HtmlElementCollection theElementCollection = webBrowser1.Document.All;
 foreach (HtmlElement curElement in theElementCollection) {
     if (curElement.GetAttribute("className") == "selectize-dropdown-content") {   
         curElement.SetAttribute("value", "2");
     }
 }
```

But nothing happens... Could anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

The attribute is called `class`.
The Javascript property (that you can access directly as a property on the element) is `clasName`, but the attribute itself is `class`.

Comment: Does this mean I need to change curElement.GetAttribute("className")  to curElement.GetAttribute("class")? Or do I need something else too? I just did this and it still doesn't do anything to the dropdown list